# custom ui local notification by user setting

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, appdelegate

I know how to make a local notification in the applicationDidEnterBackground function in AppDelegate.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

{

```
UILocalNotification * uln = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
uln.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];
uln.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

uln.alertBody = @"Did you forget something?";
uln.alertAction = @"Show me";
uln.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
//uln.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
uln.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
application.scheduledLocalNotifications = [NSArray arrayWithObject:uln];
```

}

But is that possible a user can set a time for the fireDate and a do not disturb time like late in midnight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can set the firedate property to any date in the future. Do not disturb is possible for the user to trigger himself in Settings in iOS6.

Comment: Thank you! But may I ask a simple question? I think the user should set the time in a viewController. How can I use this value in the AppDelegate file? I'm a beginner...

Comment: If you are new to programming Cocoa I suggest you begin with this tutorial http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html by Apple.

Comment: Great, so if you think my response helped you in any way please mark my answer as accepted.